# Binding to privately inherited member function

Tags: c++, stdbind, private-inheritance

I'd like to `std::bind` to a member function from a private base class, made "public" with a `using`-declaration in the derived class. Calling the function directly works, but it seems binding or using member function pointers doesn't compile:

```
#include <functional>

struct Base {
    void foo() { }
};

struct Derived : private Base { 
    using Base::foo;            
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    Derived d;

    // call member function directly:
    // compiles fine
    d.foo();

    // call function object bound to member function:
    // no matching function for call to object of type '__bind<void (Base::*)(), Derived &>'
    std::bind(&Derived::foo, d)();

    // call via pointer to member function:
    // cannot cast 'Derived' to its private base class 'Base'
    (d.*(&Derived::foo))();

    return 0;
}
```

Looking at the error messages above, the issue seems to be that `Derived::foo` is still just `Base::foo`, and I can't access `Base` through `Derived` outside `Derived` itself.

This seems inconsistent - should I not be able to use direct calls, bound functions, and function pointers interchangeably?

Is there a workaround that would let me bind to `foo` on a `Derived` object, preferably without changing `Base` or `Derived` (which are in a library I don't own)?

Comment: As a (a bit ugly) workaround you could use a lambda `[&d] () { d.foo(); }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is what the *using-declaration* actually does:

```
struct Derived : private Base { 
    using Base::foo;            
};
```

That brings `Base::foo` into public scope in `Derived`, but it doesn't create an entirely new function. It is *not* equivalent to having written:

```
struct Derived : private Base {
    void foo() { Base::foo(); }
}
```

There is still only `Base::foo()`. The *using-declaration* simply affects the access rules and the overload resolution rules. As such `&Derived::foo` really has type `void (Base::*)()` (and not `void (Derived::*)()`!), since that is the only `foo` that exists. Since `Base` is `private`, member access through a pointer to `Base` is ill-formed. I agree that this is pretty unfortunate ("inconsistent" is a good word).

You can still create a function object that calls `foo`. You just can't use the pointer to member. With C++14, this becomes straightforward if verbose (I'm assuming arbitrary arguments here and that `void foo()` is merely a simplification of the problem):

```
auto d_foo = [d](auto&&... args){ return d.foo(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }
```

With C++11, you'd have to write a type with a variadic template `operator()`.

Comment: Nice, using lambdas is an interesting way of avoiding the pointer! Is there any workaround that doesn't require C++11?

Comment: @AndersJohansson You're already using `std::bind`? Anyway, any lambda can always be written as an equivalent struct `struct D_Foo { D d; void operator()() { d.foo(); } };`

Comment: My test case is C++11 with `std::bind` but in production I am limited to C++03 with `boost::bind` - I kept the question simple because the errors are the same. Sounds like structs like the above should do the trick. Thanks!